# Как вывести значение декорированное @property на html страницу?

Tags: html, django, property

Пытаюсь использовать декоратор @property в джанго версии 1.10 :

Модель:

```
class TblReestr(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    ean13 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    reg_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    trade_name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    fabr_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    reg_data = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    mnn_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    valuta_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    num_prikaz = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)


    @property
    def current_price(self):
        surcharge = 0
        if (self.reg_price is None) or (self.reg_price == 0):
            return surcharge

        if self.reg_price < 50:
            surcharge = self.reg_price * 0.1173 + self.reg_price * 0.246
        elif 50 <= self.reg_price <= 500:
            surcharge = self.reg_price * 0.12 + self.reg_price * 0.249
        elif self.reg_price > 500:
          surcharge = self.reg_price * 0.1175 + self.reg_price * 0.243

        return self.reg_price + surcharge


    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tbl_reestr'
```

Но данные не выводятся на html страницу:

```
{% elif target == 'reestr' %}
    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table" onselectstart="return false">
        <thead>
            <tr class="info">
                <th class="text-center">Наименование</th>
                <th class="text-center">Производитель</th>
                <th class="text-center">Цена</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for item in item_list %}
            <tr class="active">
                <td>{{ item.trade_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.fabr_name}}</td>
                <td>{{ item.current_price }}</td> /* пустое */
                <td>{{ item.reg_price }}</td> /* есть  значение */
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

view.py:

```
def search(request):
    q = request.GET['q']
    target = request.GET['target']
    title = request.GET['title']
    if target == 'brak':
        item_list = TblBrak.objects.filter(trade_name__icontains=q)
    elif target == 'reestr':
        item_list = TblReestr.objects.filter(trade_name__icontains=q)
```

Подскажите, как вывести значение current_price на страницу?

Comment: Должно без проблем выводиться. Может опечатка где-то.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас item_list экземпляр TblReestr, то в шаблоне будет {{ item.current_price }}

Comment: А самое интересное, что если я попробую: @property def current_price(self): return self.reg_price . я тоже не вижу <td>{{ item.current_price }}</td>- он пуст. Но <td>{{ item.reg_price }}</td> - не пусто.  Первая идея,которая возникала - что это проблема из-за вычислений с float и decimal данными. Но даже просто вывести значение через проперти не получается. В версии 1.10 проперти работает?

Comment: property работает везде